# Oozie Hive Action stuck in PREP state and the job stuck in RUNNING state

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, job-scheduling

My Oozie Hive action is stuck in running mode forever.  No error is shown in the oozie.log file.

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2.5" name="example-wf">
<credentials>
            <credential name='hive_credentials' type='hive'>
                    <property>
                         <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
                         <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
                    </property>
            </credential>
</credentials>
<start to="hive-example"/>
<action name="hive-example" cred="hive_credentials">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.log.hive.level</name>
                    <value>DEBUG</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                    <value>hive-default.xml</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>     
        <script>script.q</script>
        <file>hive-site.xml</file>
    </hive>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
    <message>Workflow failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}] 
    </message>
   </kill>
   <end name="end"/>
   </workflow-app>
```

Also my job.properties is as shown below

```
nameNode=hdfs://hadoopmaster:54310
jobTracker=localhost:54311
workflowRoot=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/oozie-workflows
oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://hadoopmaster:54310/home/hadoopuser/Downloads/oozie
workflows
```

Also my Job log is as shown below

2014-11-13 18:19:57,697  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[hadoopuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[example-wf] JOB[0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W@:start:] Start action [0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2014-11-13 18:19:57,698  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[hadoopuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[example-wf] JOB[0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W@:start:] [***0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2014-11-13 18:19:57,698  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[hadoopuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[example-wf] JOB[0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W@:start:] [***0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2014-11-13 18:19:57,801  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[hadoopuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[example-wf] JOB[0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W@hive-example] Start action [0000001-141113180803793-oozie-hado-W@hive-example] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]

I have put my hive-site.xml in the workflow directory in oozie and uploaded the workflow directory(containing workflow.xml,hive-site.xml,hive-default.xml)  to HDFS. There is no error in the job log. So I am not sure where I am making a  mistake. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do we have hive-site.xml in your workflow after <script> tag. could you please remove it and make sure you kept the script.hql file in your hdfs directory in a place wher the workflow can access it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on my one node cluster setup on mac. I am unable to run simple map-reduce workflow which comes with oozie-examples

Answer (score 0):

How many containers does your cluster setup have ?
When you execute the workflow, one container will be occupied by oozie (it continues to hold that container till query executes) and rest will be used to execute the actual job.